# Pass selected ViewModel from WPF datagrid to new TabItem MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a tabcontrol which in the first tab loads an WPF datagrid. The rows in the datagrid are
filled with MemberViewModels.
I have managed to get the selected MemberViewModel when the datagrids selectItem is changed, but how can I pass it on to my RibbonViewModel where I want to add it to the TabItems collection with a command? The RibbonViewModel is the ViewModel of my Ribbon. On that ribbon there is a button which adds a new MemberViewModel to the tabItemsCollection, this works fine. However I want to add the selected MemberViewModel from my datagrid to be added as a new tabitem.

Code (Command) in RibbonViewModel which adds a new MemberViewModel to the TabItemsCollection

```
private void AddSelectedMemberTabItem(object notUsed)
{
  _tabViewModel.TabItems.Add(new MemberViewModel{ Header = "Member" }); // OK, this works fine
  _tabViewModel.TabItems.Add(SelectedMemberViewModel); // this doesnt work, DP SelectedMemberViewModel is never filled, don't know how to retrieve it from the selected datagrid item.
 _addOverview.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Code to retrieve the selected MemberViewModel from the selected datagriditem (in OverviewViewModel):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(MemberViewModel), typeof(OverviewViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnSelectedMemberPropertyChanged));
public MemberViewModel SelectedItem
{
   get { return (MemberViewModel)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
   set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnSelectedMemberPropertyChanged(DependencyObject m, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  var selectedMember = m.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty) as MemberViewModel;
  _ribbonViewModel.SelectedMemberViewModel = selectedMember; // error: cannot access non-static field (_ribbonViewModel) in static contect
}
```

How can I fill the _ribbonViewModel.SelectedMemberViewModel from the OnSelectedMemberPropertyChanged method on OverviewViewModel? Or am I going the wrong way with this?

Comment: can you show **relevant** XAML?

Comment: What XAML do you need? The one that binds the data to the datagrid or the one that binds the MembersViewModel to the TabControl? 
However I don't think that there is something wrong there as everything works fine, I can add, via the command on the RibbonViewModel new MemberViewModels to the tabItemCollection which results in more tabs being added. This is ok.
I just don't know how to pass the SelectedMemberViewModel(datagrid item in the OverviewViewModel) to the ribbonControlViewModel. That's my main problem..

Comment: from an outsider's perspective, it's easier to see the problem when it's NOT all text. (XAML helps to see the relations among the different parts of the app). it's easy for you to see, because you've been looking at it for N hours, where no one else here has seen it. :)

Comment: ok, I will add it this evening or tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is thet way I had to do it, this way I can pass the selected MemberViewModel from the DataGrid to an other var.

```
private static void OnSelectedMemberPropertyChanged(DependencyObject m, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  var b = m as OverviewViewModel;
  if (b == null)
    return;
  var selectedMember = m.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty) as MemberViewModel;
  b.selectedMemberChanged(selectedMember);
}
```